# When was the Democratic Party Flag Created?

Tags: united-states, democratic-party, flag

When was the Democrat Party Flag Created below, with the Donkey Symbol? Wikipedia does not say

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Democratic_Party_(United_States)

[image]

Comment: This question might be a bit closer to what you want: https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/54201/19301

Answer (score 3):

This is not an official flag for the Democrat party. Per [WorldAtlas.com](https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/why-is-the-donkey-a-symbol-of-the-democratic-party.html),

> Like most political parties around the world, the Democratic Party has both party symbol and color. However, **both the color and the symbol are unofficial** and were neither officially selected by the party official nor party members. The party’s symbol is a donkey or a jackass. Depending on which side of the political divide one is, the symbol can be interpreted either positively or negatively. To the opponents of the Democratic Party, the mascot is interpreted as lacking intelligence, strength, and often loud and stubborn yet for the Democrats, the donkey is smart, brave, and humble. Blue is considered the color of the Democratic Party while red is the color of the Republican Party. The two colors were popularized by major media houses that used them as color schemes on the electoral map.

**On the Donkey**

> Although the donkey was used as a symbol as early as 1828, Thomas Nast is often credited with making it the symbol of the Democrats. Nast, a political cartoonist, first published a cartoon depicting a live jackass kicking a dead lion in Harper’s Weekly in 1870. In 1874, He published another cartoon titled “Third Term Panic” in which he depicted a donkey in lion’s skin chasing other animals including an elephant which he referred to as “Republican vote.” Nast used the elephant to represent the Republican and a donkey to represent the Democrats. While the Donkey is synonymous with the Democratic Party, the Democrats have never made it their official party symbol but use it on a lot of their material.

**Flags with Similar Design**

[image]